# How Do I Graph 1000 Points Onto A Graph, With Different Points Being Different Colors?

Tags: r

I have been trying to have a 1000 values between 1 & 0 and if they meet specific rules, which are in the if statements, I want the points to be put on in a specific shape and color. I have tried running my code, but all I get is a graph with a point at (0, 0).

```
numOne <- sample(0:1, 1)
numTwo <- sample(0:1, 1)

plot(0,0, pch=5, col=5)

for(i in 999){
    a <- sample(0:1, 1)
    b <- sample(0:1, 1)

    if((a + b < 1) && (a - b < 0)){ lines(0, 0, pch=1, col=1) }
    if((a + b < 1) && (a - b < 0)){ lines(0, 0, pch=2, col=2) }
    if(!(a + b < 1) && (a - b < 0)){ lines(0, 1, pch=3, col=3) }
    if(!(a + b < 1) && (a - b < 0)){ lines(1, 0, pch=4, col=4) }

}
```

Comment: This code gives an the error `Error in b : object 'b' not found` where are a and b defined?

Comment: Sorry! x is actually a, and y is b. Doesn't change anything though

Comment: If you are trying to plot points,  why are using the `lines` function instead of `points`? You have four `if` statements. The first two have exactly the same condition and numbers 3 and 4 have the same condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain what you're trying to do, but here's how I would go about doing what I *think* you're trying to do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# create a dataframe with random x and y values
data <- data.frame(x = runif(n = 1000, min = 0, max = 1),
                   y = runif(n = 1000, min = 0, max = 1))

# add a new column to the data identifying the group
data <- data %>% 
           mutate(group = if_else(condition = (x + y < 1) & (x - y < 0), 
                                  true = 'a', 
                                  false = 'b'))

# plot the data with a different shape and color for each group
ggplot(data, 
       aes(x = x,
           y = y,
           color=group,
           shape=group)) +
   geom_point()
```

[image: Here's the output]